# Can I add more than one value for the?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, sqlite

```
def StatDatabase(self, x, team, position):
    # Fetches data from the FifaStats database
    # I need to add more than one variable for the different cards
    self.cur.execute("SELECT " + x + " FROM Stats WHERE Club =? AND Card =? AND Position =?",
                     (f'{team}', 'ut21  gold rare', f'{position}'))
    data = self.cur.fetchall()
    if len(data) > 1:
        updated_data = random.sample(data, 1)
        for updated_info in updated_data:
            return updated_info
    else:
        for info in data:
            return info
```

Is there a way I can represent many values that I am looking for in the ? variable. For an example where it says 'WHERE Club =? AND Card =?', can I use 'Gold' and 'Silver in the 'Card' record. How would I represent this?

Comment: Hi, you should get some basic knowledge in SQL. For your question refer to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp, especially look at operator `IN`

Comment: Thanks Alexey ill check it out!

Comment: w3... is a poor advice. Too many errors at that place.

Comment: @jarlh, interesting comment, I did not notice faulty W3schools.com tutorial chapters myself yet, do you have examples?

Comment: @StefanWuebbe, I can't remember any specific examples. I just found too many errors during my only visit.

Comment: Thanks, @jarlh , will keep eyes open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `OR` condition in where clause, as follows,

```
def StatDatabase(self, x, team, position):
    # Fetches data from the FifaStats database
    # I need to add more than one variable for the different cards
    self.cur.execute("SELECT " + x + " FROM Stats WHERE Club=? AND (Card='Gold' OR Card='Silver') AND Position=?",
                     (f'{team}', 'ut21  gold rare', f'{position}'))
    data = self.cur.fetchall()
    if len(data) > 1:
        updated_data = random.sample(data, 1)
        for updated_info in updated_data:
            return updated_info
    else:
        for info in data:
            return info
```

Like `Card` you can do same for other attributes.

EDIT:
The above query can be optimized as:

```
self.cur.execute("SELECT " + x + " FROM Stats WHERE Club=? AND Card IN ('Gold', 'Silver') AND Position=?",
                         (f'{team}', 'ut21  gold rare', f'{position}'))
```

If you want to exclude the results you can use `NOT IN`

Comment: I _think_ OP wants to pass Gold and Silver as parameter(s).

Comment: Ill try this out now

Comment: @jarlh, From the where clause it says that, he wants to check `Gold` or `Silver` values in the `Card` attribute and retrieve the data from stats table accordingly.

Comment: @jarlh, When I used another OR command, it just retrieved every player from the database, forgetting about the previous filters like the club has to be Barcelona.

Comment: "_Is there a way I can represent many values that I am looking for in the ? variable._", i.e. using parameters, not literals.

Comment: @jarlh i have edited my answer, and have added optimized part of the query, let me know if that meets your requirements

Comment: @PradeepYenkuwale : you forgot to remove one argument from the parameters.

Comment: @PtitXav : Which argument you are referring to?

Comment: @PradeepYenkuwale : in (f'{team}', 'ut21  gold rare', f'{position}' ) there are 3 parameters but only 2 '?' in sql command.